# Traceback Error

Tags: blender-osm

I am following a tutorial - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW_djQS_N8U` by `CG Geek` for **Create any City in Blender in 20 Minutes**, He is advising to use Open street map by Gumroad (https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm) and I did it, I downloaded and installed the addon, after selecting the coordinates and go to Blender and paste the coordinates and select Terrain and press import, then problem starts

Blender got hanged and later gave error - [image]

I understand from the last line that compressed file ended before EOS , then i checked from backend,I found one folder named **Terrain** was created and is having open-street-map.zip file, but that file while unzipping, not getting unzipped because of same error.. Can anyone help me on this.. thanks

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Sorry, PC got hanged,  thats why i raised question from my Mac. please excuse for this screenshot